# UITableViewCell height not dynamically being calculated even with all the constraints added

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a custom `UItableViewCell` with three labels. Two of them on the left side (like the built-in title + subtitle layout) and the other one at the right side. I'm laying out the labels programatically.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = String(describing: self)
    
    lazy var primaryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var secondaryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var tertiaryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .callout)
        return label
    }()
    
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        contentView.addSubview(primaryLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(secondaryLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(tertiaryLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tertiaryLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            tertiaryLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            tertiaryLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18),
            
            primaryLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            primaryLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            primaryLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 19),

            secondaryLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            secondaryLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: primaryLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            secondaryLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
//            secondaryLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15)
        ])
    }
}
```

I want the cell's height to be calculated dynamically. I set the `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` property values to `UITableView.automaticDimension` in the view controller when I instantiate the table view.

```
private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .grouped)
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier)
    return tableView
}()
```

But the cell still shows up like this. With the default height. Even though I have auto layout constraints laid out from top to bottom. I get no warnings in the console either.

Any idea what I am missing here?

[image]

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5jzm2qm52gljpw/programmaticrowheight.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I might also suggest making sure your constraints are fully constrained. E.g. I'd expect to see trailing anchors for the primary and secondary labels to the leading anchor of the tertiary label. And you might want to think about what you expect to happen if they will start to conflict (e.g. if they're too wide to fit all of them, do you want to escalate one's content hugging priority, or escalate the compression resistance of another, set number of lines to 0, etc.).

Comment: @Rob I get what you're saying. You're right. I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two observations:

1. Your secondary label needs a negative constant to the bottom of the container.
2. Also, your estimated row height should be some reasonable fixed value (e.g 44 or something like that ... it doesn't need to be perfect, but just some reasonable value that the table can use for estimating the height of rows that haven't been presented yet). You do *not* want to use `UITableView.automaticDimension` for `estimatedRowHeight`, only for `rowHeight`.